# Open Kendo UI TreeView node using id

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using the [Kendo UI TreeView](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html) to generate my tree. Here is the [tree documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview).

It works fine, but now I want to expand(open) a node using `id`.

I found some code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/manchagnu/CDAVZ/), but it isn't working with my code:

```
var serviceRoot = "search/treej.php";
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: serviceRoot,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "entity_id",
            hasChildren: "child"
        }
    }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: false
    },
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "value"
});


var $tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView(
    {
        select: function (event)
        {
            var $item = $(event.node);
            console.log( $item );
            alert( "selected" );
        }
    });

var $selected = $('#4'); // here i am passing static values
var $treePath = $selected.parentsUntil($tree, "li");

var treeView = $tree.data('kendoTreeView');

// Expand the tree in order to show the selected item
treeView.expand( $treePath );

// Gotta make both calls...
treeView.select( $selected );
treeView.trigger( 'select', {node: $selected} );
```

I also found this code on the Kendo website which may help:

```
var dataSource = treeview.dataSource;
var dataItem = dataSource.get(5); // find item with id = 5
var node = treeview.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
```

Comment: That actually looks like it should work fine. Are you sure that `var $selected = $('#4');` is actually finding an element?

Answer (score 1):

can you try replacing

```
var $selected = $('#4');
```

with your second part

```
var dataSource = treeview.dataSource;
var dataItem = dataSource.get(4); // find item with id = 4
var $selected = treeview.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
```